# Python - TypeError: iterable argument required

Tags: python, list, typeerror, iterable

I get **"TypeError: iterable argument required"** when i try to execute the code below:

```
for i in range(len(SE_FE_Lists)):                    
    print "** ", SE_FE_Lists[i]["List_contents"]
    if ":" in SE_FE_Lists[i]["List_contents"]:
        print ": ", SE_FE_Lists[i]
        print "*--* ", SE_FE_Lists[i]["List_contents"]
    if " " in SE_FE_Lists[i]["List_contents"]:
        print "Space :", SE_FE_Lists[i]
        print "*--* ", SE_FE_Lists[i]["List_contents"]
```

The error is located in the line **if ":" in List[i]["List_contents"]:**

The contents of the list :

```
[{'List_selection': 'List1', 'List_contents': '1:4'}, {'List_selection': 'List2', 'List_contents': '1 2 4'}, {'List_selection': 'List3',
 'List_contents': 1}]
```

As output i get :

```
**  1:4

:  {'List_selection': 'List1', 'List_contents': '1:4'}

*--*  1:4

**  1 2 4

Space : {'List_selection': 'List2', 'List_contents': '1 2 4'}

*--*  1 2 4

**  1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are the contents of `List`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want to iterate over items of your object List, you should use the pythonic way of doing it :

```
for item in List:

    if ":" in item["List_contents"]:
        print "*--* ", item["List_contents"]
    if " " in item["List_contents"]:
        print "*--* ", item["List_contents"]
```

for the error you encounter, it looks like your `List` object is not a dictionnary list.

EDIT :

after your edition, the problem is due to the last item of your List : `{'List_selection': 'List3', 'List_contents': 1}`, here the member 'List_contents' is an integer, and python can't find ":" in an integer...
If you can't modify the content of the list, try to force python to use a string with the `str()` method :

```
if ":" in str(item["List_contents"]):
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there is an integer in your dictionary, not an iterable:

```
{'List_selection': 'List3', 'List_contents': 1}
```

This line:

```
if ":" in SE_FE_Lists[i]["List_contents"]:
```

is looking for ": " in the integer `1`. the `in` operator requires an iterable, not an integer, so that's apparently the error. If the list contents looked like this it should work:

```
{'List_selection': 'List3', 'List_contents': '4 5 6'}
```